# Paperclip validating when no attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a rails model in which an image is uploaded using Paperclip.

I have added validation of size for the image.

```
validates_attachment-size :image, less_than => 5.megabytes
```

When trying to save the model when there is no attachment it validates the image which is absent and fails the save.

I need to save the model if there is no image and the validation should work only when there is an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
validate :image_present

def image_present
  if image.present? && image_file_size < 2.megabytes
    errors.add(:file_size, "file size must be between 0 and 2 megabytes.")
  end
end
```

Here, the validation will work if there is image present in the model and will skip the validation if there is no image.

Comment: Nice answer Aswathy :)

Answer (score 1):

First of you have a typo in your code. `validates_attachment-size` should be `validates_attachment_size`.

You wanted to do:

```
validates_attachment_size :image, less_than => 5.megabytes
```

This built in helper would work normally. But, this validation will force the validation of an actual attachment, means it won't work if the image is not present.

So, if you want to be sure if an image is present, you can add a `custom validator` where you will check the image presence. Like this:

```
validate :image_presence_and_size

def image_presence_and_size
  if image.present? && image_file_size < 5.megabytes
    errors.add(:file_size, "file size must be less than 5 megabytes.")
  end
end
```